# For...loop to call TextBox and Label indexer(i) to show ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I do something to create some textbox with index number in aspxTextBox, or maybe other controls too, like Label. I think want to use them to show array text with indexer...

```
string[] TEST= new string[2] {"This is TextBox1(0)","This is TextBox1(1)"}; //this is text-array
for (int i=0;i<=1;i++)
{
   TextBox1(i).text="";   //how to draw this control too with DevExpr:ASPxTextBox?
   TextBox1(i).text=TEST[i];
}
```

any idea...  I would like to do this within ASP.NET using the C# language.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
 string[] TEST= new string[2] {"This is TextBox1(0)","This is TextBox1(1)"}; //this is text-array
 for (int i=0;i<=1;i++)
 {
 TextBox txt = new TextBox();
 txt.ID = "textBox"+i;
 txt.Text = Test[i];
 form1.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

if you are making controls dynamically then you will have to take care about their location as well

Comment: It's works... Thanks sir. :D (y)

Comment: Just clearing the point of question, but i cant make it(question) so simple like Mr. Amit think. so... that is ~dynamic control... Thanks again.